# Adding multiple uiview to uipageviewcontroller instead of using UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

Is there any examples where i can add multiple uiviews to uipageviewcontroller instead of using UIViewController.  I have a pageViewController and i want to add couple of UIViews to this controller.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why don't you want to add view controllers?

Comment: In that case, why not use a `UIScrollView` with `pagingEnabled` set to YES?